# WMctrl использование через SSH

Tags: linux

Есть ли возможность узнать, какие окна запущены на другом компьютере утилитой WMCtrl находясь подключённым через SSH?При попытке проверить список запущенных окон пишет:    **wmctrl -d    Cannot open dysplay**.Я так понимаю, это связано с тем, что программа в любом случае пытается показать мне список моих окон, не смотря на то что, я подключен к другому компьютеру через SSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку wmctrl - это программа X, то требуется знание двух величин для корректной работы:

- адрес экрана (DISPLAY),
- пароль экрана (XAUTHORITY)

Получить эти значения можно разными способами, например, добавив в `~/.profile` строки, сохраняющие значения в файл

```
case $DISPLAY in*)     export | grep -E ' (DISPLAY|XAUTHORITY)=' > ~/use_display_xauthority.sh    ;;esac
```

При этом во время подключения по ssh выполнить

```
~/use_display_xauthority.shscreen
```

Теперь wmctrl должно работать.